# Discord.py удаление всех сообщений в текстовом канале

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Давно пытаюсь сделать очистку сообщений (все) в своем Discord боте по команде: /clear , но никак не получается. Помогите пожалуйста, слейте код очистки пожалуйста. Одна из моих попыток:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('/clear'):
        tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Clearing messages...')
        async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel):
            await client.delete_message(msg)
```

Что  я делаю не правильно? У меня просто закрывается файл (при открытии). Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Жаль, что мне не ответят

Comment: Если вы давно пытаетесь, то наверное уже есть какой-то код, который не работает? Приведите в вопросе свои попытки решить задачу.

Comment: Привел одну из попыток.

Comment: Вы мне поможете?

Comment: Именно кодом? Вряд ли. Но вы уже помогли сами себе хотя бы тем, что привели код (хотя и не написали, что за ошибку он выдаёт или как ведёт себя при отладке: заходит ли вообще по условию, например). Вы кстати отдаёте себе отчёт, что гарантировать что ответ появится в точно определённый срок тут никто не может?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить от администратора

Comment: Пробовал от админки - нет

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, стоит начать с пересмотра кода. Что конкретно не так с кодом вы не указали, так что скажу основные вещи исходя из самого кода.

Учитывая рейт лимиты дискорда, удалять даже 100 сообщений из канала вашим способом займет вечность. Вместо этого можно использовать метод `Client.purge_from` Пример:

```
client.purge_from(message.channel)
```

Документация: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.Client.purge_from

По сути, это в 100 раз увеличит скорость удаления. Но есть ли в нем вообще смысл? Почему бы просто, например, не пересоздать канал с идентичными параметрами?

P.S. рекомендую использовать последнюю версию библиотеки, а не старую из async ветки.

Answer (score 0):

channel объект имеет метод history. Только что копался в библиотеке и в discord/abc.py есть функция _purge_helper с примером использования

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).